# java.awt.Robot emulating Keys on different Keyboard Layouts and locale

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot, keyboard-layout

I have a Java remote application which emulates keyboard on remote PC using `AWT` Robot. If the remote user presses the extended keys on the keyboard and the keyboard locale is not `en_US`, the extended keys will not display. To be specific the `AWT` `Robot` will give an Invalid key code exception when the extended key is pressed.

I did some research and found out that `AWT Robot` does not support different keyboard layouts and default locale supported is `en_US`.

I'm hoping some people have an idea how to support multiple keyboard layouts & locale using Robot class or any alternatives in java.